# creating an OpenCascade Module for SALOME in the Windows Development Environment

Tags: cross-platform, opencascade

I read a tutorial on how to do that in LINUX, but it looks like this cant be ported to windows so easily. SALOME gives us a development environment for windows and claims its crossplattform:

http://www.salome-platform.org/downloads/current-version

But the documentation does not specify the module creation process in windows (the documentation is only downloadable so i cant link it). To follow the LINUX tutorial, one has to find and edit several files that are missing in the windows distribution. Mainly these are files that are used in the make process of the linux salome module creation.

I hope anyone has some experience in this field.

Answer (score 0):

SALOME doesn't support Windows currently, as the 3rd parties dependencies.
http://www.salome-platform.org/forum/forum_9/975821878